# Select first record found

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Suppose I have the following table structure

```
 ________________________
|      |         |       |         
|Col1  |  Col2   |  Col3 | 
|______|_________|_______|
|      |         |       |         
| 123  |   245   |  aaa  | 
|______|_________|_______|
|      |         |       |         
| 123  |  245    |  bbb  | 
|______|_________|_______|
```

I need to update the first row but not the second, but I don't want to reference Col3.

If I do

```
 UPDATE table SET col1 = '789' WHERE col2='245'
```

It will update both rows. How could I craft the above query to only update the FIRST record it finds if the `WHERE` clause is to be kept at `col2='245'`?

Comment: and you dont have a primary key in the table ?

Comment: ... and without referencing Col3, how do you know whether it will update `aaa` or `bbb` ?

Comment: If that really is all your table there's no way to guarantee an update to a specific row without referencing `Col3`.

Comment: I do have a primary key. But I can't reference that. I also can't reference the third column. It doesn't matter whether `aaa` or `bbb` is updated. What matters is that the top row is updated (ie the first one that it finds).

Comment: As it stands, this question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not ordering, there is no *first* row to update, it will just "pull one out of the available ones".

If you're clear about a *pseudorandom* one of the two rows will be updated, you can use `LIMIT` with the update;

```
UPDATE mytable SET col1 = '789' WHERE col2='245' LIMIT 1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d726e5/1).

Comment: When I say first, I just means first that it finds. If I am not ordering my table, the first that it finds will always be the same, is that correct?

Comment: @user1775598 No, there is no such guarantee. Without ORDER BY, adding an index or updating a row or even if a row is cached since a previous query can very well change the order in which rows are returned or updated.